# Gazebo ignition maritime plugins

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-ignition

I've found some tutorials about how to simulate a maritime robot using gazebo (https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/tutorials.html) and if I'm not wrong these are related to gazebo classic. I wanted to know if I can use these plugins in gazebo harmonic/garden (that as far as can I recall is part of gazebo ignition) or if there is any alternative to these plugins.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That website is actually for Gazebo Harmonic.